# Jquery get checked inputs from Div #ID matching Select Option

Tags: jquery

I'm need to get all checked inputs from div ID that match the Select Value of the dropdown select option.

For Example :

If option one is selected in dropdown 
and if user click on inputs in option two or option three nothing happens but when user click on inputs in options one the checked items value is returned.

Similarly If option two is selected in dropdown and if user click on inputs in option two the checked items value is returned from div #two.

Similarly If option three is selected in dropdown and if user click on inputs in option three the checked items value is returned from div #three.

```html
<br>
<label class="title">Select Option</label>
<div class="options">
    <select class="select-menu-type">
        <option value="one"> Option one </option>
        <option value="two"> Option two </option>
        <option value="three"> Option three </option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<div id="one">
    <label class="title">option one</label>
    <fieldset class="options-block">
        <input type="radio" name="option-one-a" value="red">
        <label for="red">Red</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-one-a" value="blue">
        <label for="blue">Blue</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-one-a" value="green">
        <label for="green">Green</label>

       <br>

        <input type="radio" name="option-one-b" value="grey">
        <label for="grey">grey</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-one-b" value="purple">
        <label for="purple">purple</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-one-b" value="lime">
        <label for="lime">lime</label>

    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <label class="title">option two</label>
    <fieldset class="options-block">
        <input type="radio" name="option-two-a" value="yellow">
        <label for="yellow">yellow</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-two-a" value="brown">
        <label for="brown">brown</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-two-a" value="orange">
        <label for="orange">orange</label>

        <br>

        <input type="radio" name="option-two-b" value="amber">
        <label for="amber">amber</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-two-b" value="blue">
        <label for="blue">Blue</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-two-b" value="green">
        <label for="green">Green</label>        
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="three">
    <label class="title">option three</label>
    <fieldset class="options-block">
        <input type="radio" name="option-three-a" value="pink">
        <label for="pink">pink</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-three-a" value="black">
        <label for="black">black</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-three-a" value="white">
        <label for="white">white</label>

        <br>

        <input type="radio" name="option-three-b" value="red">
        <label for="red">Red</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-three-b" value="blue">
        <label for="blue">Blue</label>
        <input type="radio" name="option-three-b" value="green">
        <label for="green">Green</label>

    </fieldset>

</div>
<br>
<p class="result"> Your Clicked : </p>
```

Comment: Do you have some code that you've tried and would like help with? Generally it's best, when asking a question, not to assume we'll just write the code for you. Someone may very well do so, but that's not going to help much when you need to do a similar task again...

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't hide the other div box, if one option selected?

If option one selected hide div #two and div #three

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedOption = $('.select-menu-type').val();

$('#' + selectedOption + ' input:checked') // holds all checked inputs inside the "selected" div
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the value of the dropdown in the selector for the radio buttons.

```
var checked = $("#" + $(".select-menu-type")).find(":radio:checked");
```